# Using subcaption package, how can I make subfigures have main Figure numbering?

Tags: numbering, captions, subcaption

I have a figure as follows, and it captions the two figures with (a) and (b) but I would like to have them labelled as Figure 1 and Figure 2. The figure numbering should be consistent with the rest of the document (ie not a separate numbering).

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{rolling_sml}
        \caption{Hot rolling to produce a rod of the required diameter.}\label{fig:rolling}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{thread400x}
        \caption{A microstructure sketch of the grains near the thread of one of the screws.}\label{fig:screwthread}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Actual appearance]

This actual appearance is not what I want. Is there any way of making the captions just follow the main numbering?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if you use `minipage`s instead of `subfigure`s you should get what you want.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}` should help

Comment: Thanks, using minipage produces exactly the right results. (The renewcommand doesn't leave the numbering consistent with the rest of the document)

Comment: @OscarS: Since you have not provided any document at all, the consistency of your numbering scheme is not obvious to us, so the `\renewcommand` was a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `subfigure` environment is nothing but a `minipage` environment that provides some extra styling for the `\caption` command. Since you don't need this styling, don't use `subfigure`s. Instead, use `minipage`s directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{rolling_sml}
\caption{Hot rolling to produce a rod of the required diameter.}
\label{fig:rolling}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{thread400x}
\caption{A microstructure sketch of the grains near the thread of one of the screws.}
\label{fig:screwthread}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```